# Get the date for each duplicated row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made a query to get how many products are sold more than one time and it worked.

Now I want to show the transaction date for each of these duplicated sales, but when I insert the date on the select it brings me a lot less rows: something is going wrong. The query without the date returns 9855 rows and with the date just 36 rows.

Here is the query I'm doing:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, 
       ProductName, 
       QtyOfSales = COUNT(*) 
FROM product_sales
WHERE ProductID = 1 -- Product Sold ID
  AND ProductName IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY ProductName, 
         TransactionDate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Perhaps a subquery? Can you help in that regard?

Comment: Adding the date changes the groupings; you likely will need to now use a CTE/derived table with a windowed `COUNT` instead now.

Comment: Would help us a lot if you show sample source data and expected output of your query

Comment: Based on your query, can a single `ProductId` have multiple `ProductName`s? It implies that they can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the corresponding `COUNT` window function, that will find the amount of transactions by partitioning on the "*ProductName*" as required:

```
WITH cte AS(
       SELECT TransactionDate,
              ProductName, 
              COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductName) AS QtyOfSales 
       FROM product_sales
       WHERE ProductID = 1 -- Product Sold ID
         AND ProductName IS NOT NULL 
)
SELECT DISTINCT TransactionDate,
                ProductName 
FROM cte 
WHERE QtyOfSales > 1
```

Comment: Thanks lemon, it worked perfectly for my case!